# Access to polymer function in javascript

Tags: javascript, cordova, polymer

I use Polymer with Apache Cordova.

I want to bind the "back button" of android in order to close a dialog window.
Unfortunately, to access the shadowDom, I am inside Polymer js. But backbutton seems not accessible from Polymer 'object'.

Here is my code :

```
<script>
    Polymer({        
            // handle back button
            toggleDialog: function(event, detail, sender) {
                var dialog = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#askOptionImgDialog');
                dialog.toggle();

            },
            ready: function() {
                document.addEventListener("backbutton", this.toggleDialog(), false);
            }
        });
</script>
```

Do nothing.

I tried this :

```
<script>
    Polymer({        
            // handle back button
            toggleDialog: function(event, detail, sender) {
                var dialog = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#askOptionImgDialog');
                dialog.toggle();

            }
        });
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", ???????.toggleDialog(), false);
</script>
```

And the back button seems triggered but I don't know how to access to the polymer function outside.
Any Idea ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just wrapping everything in one closure?

```
<script>
  Polymer({domReady:
      function() {
        document.addEventListener("backbutton",
            function(event, detail, sender) {
              var dialog = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#askOptionImgDialog');
              dialog.toggle();
            }, false);
       }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Because I have to 'toggle' this window also on-tap of an element and I don't want to duplicate code.

Comment: Can you rephrase that @FrPolymer? What do you need to toggle and when?

Comment: When a user touch (on tap) de button, I displayed a paper-dialog. I want to let the user close this paper-dialog by pressing the 'back button' of his phone.